# Displaying Overlay images over thumbnail of category type?

Tags: php

How would I place an overlay image over a thumbnail of a certain category.

For example. I have the category "Videos" how would i place a playbutton image over the thumbnail, while making it all link to the post.

But i have different thumbnail sizes as well.

Comment: [CSS Overlay images](http://stackoverflow.com/q/403478/1287812).

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do what you want to do. Here is a tutorial that will show you how to get it done. Just alter the css to fit your needs

http://webdesignandsuch.com/create-overlay-on-image-hover-jquery-css3/

as far as linking. You can use WordPress code for that. Such as

```
 <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="your image with overlay"></a>
```